# how to user select single row from all rows in database using php?

Tags: php

how to user select single row from all rows in database using php?
http://kaybs.in/sandscricketassociation/profile1.php
This is my link

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself.

Comment: single row from all rows? what's this means????

Comment: did you already tried something?

Comment: for example,username and password it's correct then displays selected user information from database

Comment: for example,username and password it's correct then displays selected user information details for that user from database

Answer (score 1):

A query like this???

```
"SELECT <fields>
 FROM <table>
 WHERE <field> = <data>
 LIMIT 1";
```